# getfiles is ignoring current user folder?

Tags: c#

The folder C:\Users contain 3 subfolders :

```
  C:\Users\hacen
  C:\Users\_rafi_000
  C:\Users\Public
```

However, when I call :

```
  DirSearch(@"C:\Users\", "*.jpg");
```

It outputs all jpg filenames from Public and hacen, but not from   **_rafi_000**    which is the folder of current user.

Here is the function :

```
       static void DirSearch(string dir, string pattern)
    {

        try
        {

            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir, pattern))

            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);

            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {

                DirSearch(d, pattern);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
           //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

**EDIT:**

I tried with the code below and it works. So it isn't an access denied problem :

```
     DirSearch("C:\Users\_rafi_000\","*.jpg");
```

**What I noticed so far is that unlike other subfolders,  the folder _rafi_000 cannot be ranamed when I press F2**

Comment: Probably the `catch` should be allowed to display the exception (if any)

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) with [SearchOption Enumeration with AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you running your program as an administrator?

Comment: It sounds weird.. but what happens if you try to enumerate the `_rafi_000` folder **before** the `hacen` folder. Does it populate the files then?

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to where the jpg are stored and how reparse points work in later windows version.

I suggest looking at:

Directory Searching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Reparse Point Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365503(VS.85).aspx

I ran your code and it works fine in windows XP:

```
C:\Users\hacen\bar.jpg
C:\Users\Public\bar1.jpg
C:\Users\_rafi_000\bar2.jpg
```

Comment: Did the code gives you the content of your user folder ? Don't create _rafi_000 but instead use your own user folder and tell me whether it works ?

Comment: Yes running on my user folder also produces the file names, even deep rooted files:

C:\Documents and Settings\Mohamsha\Desktop\eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524\themes\purpleMesh\graphics\contentpage\webrsrc_wtr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
void DirSearch(string dir, "*.JPG")  
 { 
     foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.JPG")) 
     { 
         Console.WriteLine(f);
     } 
     foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))  
     { 
         DirSearch(d);
     } 
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct.
Perhaps [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) can help?

If the code is fine, it must be something else. I understand that you can run the code directly against the directory which is causing you a problem (which is surprising) - but I think Process Mon could help.